# JsDoc toolkit and Namespace - Warning trying to .. without

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

I am using [jsdoc-toolkit](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/DocExamples) with the [namespace library of Mike Koss](http://code.google.com/p/g02me/source/browse/trunk/app/scripts/namespace.js). The code looks like this

```
namespace.module('a.b', // this is the namespace

// @param {Object} exports visible classes within this namespace
// @param {function} required other namespaces
function (exports, require) {

var entityBase = require("a.base");
var util = require("a.util");

// @class BlaBla
// @constructor
// @property {String} ..
// @property {String} ..
// @property {String} ..
// @property {..} ....
// @param {Array} ...
// @param {X} [optionalParam]
exports.MyClass = function (...) {
```

Creating documentation I get the following message **and no documentation is created** at all for this class.

```
>> WARNING: Trying to document exports.MyClass without first documenting exports.
```

I have tried to overcome the issue with the param lines - no success.

```
// @param {Object} exports visible classes within this namespace
// @param {function} required other namespaces
function (exports, require) {
```

Any idea how to overcome the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have switched to [JsDoc 3](https://github.com/micmath/jsdoc#readme) (https://github.com/micmath/jsdoc#readme). This support modules and hence the above namespace library.