# VS2010 convert comments from // to block comments /** */

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Since I am using [JsDoc3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7379775/jsdoc-toolkit-and-namespace-warning-trying-to-without) I need to convert single line comments to block comments

```
// @param ..
// @class ...
```

to

```
/**
* @param
* @classs ...
*/
```

Is there a shortcut / addon for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do a simple Find/Replace on the string "//"? Do a Find Next (just once) and Replace the first one with

> /**

In the options, search UP on the document (to get the last instance in the document). Move down a line and insert

> */

Finally, do a find/replace on all the instances of "//" with " * ".

Comment: Nope, I must only apply the /** */ block comments to the "header" of methods, classes, and properties. General // comments I need to keep as such - this rules out any global "//" replacements